# Site.com Data Repeater filter Criteria Query String URL not working for two different scenarios

Tags: rest-api, site.com, data-repeater

I have one filter for Alphabetic sort and other for search facility on the website. 
The Alphabetic sort is working at all times but the search filter (having contains operator) works only when I remove the alphabetic sort.

Is there any way I can fetch Salesforce data through some API (e.g. REST API) or any integration possible in Site.com pages? I need other data such as recently viewed or queried.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have got something for the Webservices in Site.com part here: http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/category/siteforce/
I have tried to implement this and getting the data from Salesforce custom object successfully.

Still I am unable to figure out the issue with Data repeater filter criteria results for two separate conditions.